# Passing parameters in Shell command in VB 6

Tags: vb6

I have 2 EXEs in VB 6. EXE 1 calls the other EXE2 through shell command

EXE1 :
Shell(PathName\EXE2,0)

Now all I want is to pass a string type variable to EXE2 which I wish to receive in that EXE2.
How can I achieve the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply append the string (possibly quoted) to the end of the filename:

```
Shell("""PathName.exe"" wibble", vbNormalFocus)
```

or:

```
Shell("""PathName.exe"" ""wibble"" ""wibble 2""", vbNormalFocus)
```

This value can then be read in the other application using the `Command$()` function which will include everything after the path name and space, including any quotes around the parameters  (e.g. `"wibble" "wibble 2"`).