# How to pass variable by the shell method in vb?

Tags: shell, command-line, vb6

I saw this question 
[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076225/passing-parameters-in-shell-command-in-vb-6)

In this the string was "wibble", but what if my string is in a variable. Then how would I pass it.
Example

```
 Dim lng As String
```

how do I pass lng as a command line to the exe application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to receive command line parameters:

command line passed to vn6 application is captured by a global string variable called "command"

NOTE: That variable will contain entire command line, not in array like in case of C. You would need to parse command variable explicitly.

e.g. somewhat like:

```
Dim lng As String
Dim lngValue As long
....
....
sub main
lng = command$
lngValue = val(lng)
....
....
end sub
```

---

If you want to send command line parameters:

you can simply do it using string concatenation:

```
Shell("""PathName.exe"" """ & lng & """ ""wibble 2""", vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Yep, simple string concatenation. There is nothing special about using it in a command line (except maybe escaping any quotes)

Comment: @anishsane Thank you very much anish, this worked, I was using & but not so many quotes, could you explain why there are so many quotes in the calling of shell function ?

Comment: Just like you use \" for putting quotes in a C string, you need to use "" to put a quote in a VB string.