# Run an executable file with parameters using "Shell"

Tags: .net, vb.net, shell

My problem that mess with game ever laid direct in vb and yet will no longer tested and works in start.bat see the code:

```
@echo off
    start main.exe gt550
exit
```

would like to know the following, how can I run this command in Shell? well tried and failed

```
Shell(CurDir() & "\" & "cabalmain.exe", "breaklee")
```

I just want to run a program. exe inside the shell over with a parameter.

Comment: It's not necessary to SHOUT your questions here. We can all read very well. :-) There's a Shift key on your keyboard for a reason. Questions posted in ALL CAPS are hard to read, and won't get you help any faster. The Shift key is on your keyboard for a reason. Please use it. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but I did not scream, I did not see where I cried ..

Comment: Your original question asked "PARAMETER RUN WITH THE SHELL". Typing in ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING. Please don't do it. (DON'T TYPE ALL IN CAPITAL LETTERS.) Use your Shift key to type properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `Process.Start` instead of `Shell`, as `Shell` is a holdover from the VB 6 days and `Process.Start` is built into the .NET Framework.

Here is an example of running Microsoft Word via the command line, passing it parameters, including file name and any flags:

```vb
Sub Main()
    OpenMicrosoftWord("C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Office\Gears.docx")
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Open the path parameter with Microsoft Word.
''' </summary>
Private Sub OpenMicrosoftWord(ByVal f As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE"
    startInfo.Arguments = f
    Process.Start(startInfo)
End Sub
```

Comment: is already used the Process.Start, plus the game closes after a few minutes over there did. bat and it worked so I'm trying to use the Shell.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have no idea what Leonardo is trying to say in his comment. Please don't write VB 6 code in VB.NET.

Comment: If you *must* use `Shell`, find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076225/passing-parameters-in-shell-command-in-vb-6), in a question appropriately tagged "vb6".