# how to call exe file in vb6 with multiple parameters

Tags: vb6

I tried With below code

```
Dim pthName As String
Dim Parms As String
Dim RpNo As Integer
Dim glngbr As Long
Dim PrtVw As String
pthName = "D:\Sample.exe"
RpNo = 1
PrtVw = "V"
glngbr = 84003
Shell pthName & Parms
```

I am getting error "Run time error 53 ".

i tried without parameter its working

```
Shell pthName
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters in Shell command in VB 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076225/passing-parameters-in-shell-command-in-vb-6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
Shell "D:\Sample.exe" & " " & Param_1, Param_2
```

Comment: Shell "D:\Sample.exe" & " " & RpNo, PrtVw, glngbr.  Am getting error "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Shell "D:\Sample.exe" & " " & RpNo & " " & PrtVw & " " & glngbr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the api shellexecute http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238245

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                    ByVal lpFile As String, _
                    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_HIDE As Long = 0
Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1
Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Long = 3
Private Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED As Long = 2

private Sub exec_program()
    ShellExecute App.hInstance, "Open", "D:\Sample.exe", "Parms", "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Shell command, or ShellExecute either for that matter.  There's a simpler solution: the global `VBA.Command` object contains whatever string you added when you called your exe file.  For example, if you enter `myproject.exe hello world` on the command line, `VBA.Command` will contain the string `hello world`.

If you want multiple command line arguments, you can just put them all on the command line separated by a known delimiter such as `/`.  Then you can use the Split function to break them up.

Read [This](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?517473-Classic-VB-How-can-I-use-command-line-parameters-in-my-program).  It will tell you all about it, including how to use it in the IDE without having to test against a compiled version.